# How to add gradient in the background except a specific box in css

Tags: html, css

I have tried to create a box for my specific content and I want a white background in that. On the other hand, I want a gradient background on the whole screen except that box.

After I tried it, I only got white background on the whole screen.

Here is the related HTML and CSS.

```css
.div1{ 
  position: absolute;
    top: 46%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;`enter code here`
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div1 text-center">
  <h1 class="heading">Weather App</h1>
  <form method="post" action="/" class="">
    <label class="askingInfo" for="cityInput">City Name : </label>
    <input id="cityInput" type="text" name="cityName">
    <button class="btn-lg btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Go</button>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the gradient background to body so it can fill the whole screen except that box. Something like that:

```
 body {
    background: linear-gradient(
    171deg,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 40%,
    rgba(110, 110, 110, 1) 100%
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The body has the gradient on it.
The div has a background of white.

I would also recommend using a fieldset tag around the form to indicate semantically that everything inside it is related.
Here is a codepen showing the outcome. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/CA-Carl/pen/rNjjdqw)

Alternatively, this is the code

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 1800px;
  height: 100vh;
//This is the Background we set
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center center, transparent,rgb(33,33,33)),repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(33,33,33) 0px, rgb(33,33,33) 2px,transparent 2px, transparent 10px,rgb(33,33,33) 10px, rgb(33,33,33) 11px,transparent 11px, transparent 21px),repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(47,47,47) 0px, rgb(47,47,47) 4px,transparent 4px, transparent 8px),linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(33,33,33),rgb(33,33,33));
}
.div1{ 
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 25vw;
  top: 25vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vh;
  padding: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: white;
}
fieldset{
  
  border: 1px solid rgb(92, 84, 62);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  
}
legend{
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(92, 84, 62);
}
input:focus{
  background: rgb(212, 255, 254);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div1 text-center">
    <fieldset>
    <legend class="heading">Weather App</legend>
    <form method="post" action="/" class="">
        <label class="askingInfo" for="cityInput">City Name : 
            <input id="cityInput" type="text" name="cityName">
        </label>
        <button class="btn-lg btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</body>
```